# How can I check if a `let` variable has been declared on ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, let

Unlike traditional var-declared variables, which are attached to the entire enclosing, function scope regardless of where they appear — `let` declarations attach to the block scope but *are not initialized until they appear in the block*

So :

```
console.log( a ); // undefined
console.log( b ); // ReferenceError!

var a;
let b;
```

So it seems that hoisting is not applied here.

**Question**

If so , how can I safely  check if the variable has been declared ?

NB - The option I see is try/catch and of course always put the `let` variables first at scope. but still my question remains

Comment: You can't check whether any variable (either `let` or `var`) has been declared. You can only check whether they have been defined. Why are you trying to do this anyway? What's your use case?

Comment: @AaditMShah The case is learning . with var I could do  : `if (typeof a ==='undefined')`

Comment: Edited my comment. What you are doing is checking whether the variable has been defined. You are not checking whether it has been declared.

Comment: Is it really learning when it's trying to do something with `let` that was not intended to do. It's a block scope so there is no reason to check for it outside that block.

Comment: @gillesc Who said i'm checking it outside the block ?It is very simple. Inside a block , to check if a `let` variable has been declared.

Comment: Gotta be one hell of a block to have test for `let` variables inside it.

Comment: Suppose you can test if a variable has been created via *let*. What are you going to do if it has or hasn't? It is impossible to tell if a variable has been declared or not without the use of *try..catch* or messy use of *delete*, and only then for globals. For locals, *delete* doesn't work either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> it seems that hoisting is not applied here.

Not exactly. The variable still covers the complete scope, the binding is created when the scope is entered just like with `var`s.

But you're right, in contrast to `var`s it is not initialised with `undefined` immediately, only when the `let` statement is evaluated. The area from the top of the scope to there is called *temporal dead zone* - the identifier is bound, but will always throw a `ReferenceError` when used.

> How can I safely check if the variable has been declared?

You cannot, just as you cannot for `var`s<sup>1</sup>. You don't need this anyway.

<sub>1: Let's ignore global variables<sup>2</sup> that become properties of the global object here.

2: `var`/`function`/`function*`-declared variables, I mean. Lexical bindings (`let`, `const`) indeed don't become global properties.</sub>

Comment: Bergi : IMHO with `var` I _can_ check  via `typeof` ( except the situation where it has undefined value `var g=undefined`)  and also with `if ('x' in window)` ( for global - not for scopes.)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Not sure what you mean, nor what your use case is. `typeof x` does always return `"undefined"` if the variable does not exist or has the value `undefined`. Regardless whether it was declared or not.

Comment: You said : _You cannot, just as you cannot for vars_  — I just mentioned that I _can_ check the _existence_ of  variable via `if ('a' in window) {..}` ( but it will work only for global scope)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: I thought you meant one could use `typeof` for that.

Answer (score 5):

That would be the closest to what you are looking for:

```
try {
    console.log(typeof mima); // or any other use of variable
    let mima = 'no ni ma';
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error); // “Uncaught ReferenceError: mima is not defined(…)”

    // and then taking some actions regarding the situation
}
```

Though, its usefulness is rather debatable. But if I had to check `let`’ed variable, I would go with something like that. However, mind you that you cannot safely create missing variable with `let`, as it’s surrounded by `catch` block. But it will not break the code.